# How to do edit text multi line with fixed height and width with out scrollbar?

Tags: android

I woud like to EditText multi line text with fixed height and width without  scrollbar. The scrollbar stays and I don't want it.
This my code for EditText:

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/write_text"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_200mdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapWords"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textSize="@dimen/xxxl_fontsize"
            android:lines="3"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:maxLength="144"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            />
```

I have tried a lot but the scrollbar remains, I want the fixed height and width with `inputType="textMultiLine|textCapWords"`  without scrollbar

Can any one help me.

Comment: And what you already getting?

Comment: Your both features are colliding. fixed height and not scroll . In that way there will a limit of max character . Isn't it?

Comment: I've got a fixed height and width with inputType="textMultiLine|textCapWords"  and just in 3 lines but there scroll @Ibrahim

Comment: Yes I did maxlength ="144" but when the number of characters ends I stop typing I want the user only to write in 6 a lines
I want this feature to be written above image So I do not want anything hidden in the scrollbar so I can do a movement  feature @ADM

Comment: Make textMultiLine as input type . and use MinHeight attribute with wrap_content height . otherwise if you want exact height then you need to calculate and set it at runtime. Got my point ?

Comment: I did it but the scrolling stays ,ِDo  inputType="textMultiLine" by default add scroll ,and I deleted this two lines`   android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:scrollbars="none" `   When the number of lines exceeds three, the spool starts to stop @ِADM

Comment: On which android version you are testing ? I have tested it its not showing scroll bars.

Comment: In my test is shown scroll True hidden but when I write more than three lines exist scroll <my android version is 21 API

Comment: Really thanks for your time and help @ADM

Comment: bravo !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Not so far there is a scroll but I thank you for your time .

Answer (score 0):

you must not make the height warp_content.

```
    android:layout_height="@dimen/yourHeight"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but I did that before and I've got a fixed height and width with inputType="textMultiLine|textCapWords" and just in 3 lines but there scroll